# Update response data from a route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route:

```
 .../first
```

this call below function:

```
function first() {
   $data['first'] = 1;
   return response()->json($data);
}
```

Then I'm working on new route:

```
.../second
```

this call:

```
function second() {
   ...
   if ($condition) {
      return redirect()->to('.../first');
   }
}
```

this is return:

```
{
  "first": 1
}
```

I want to have a result, when I call second() function, look like:

```
{
  "first": 1,
  "second" : 2
}
```

How can I do that, I'm trying to put the key `second` to response from redirect() (`Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse as array`)
, as well as check condition :

```
function first() {
   $data['first'] = 1;
   if (Request::is('.../second') { 
      $data['second'] = 2; // but this never execute,request now is ".../first"
   }
   return response()->json($data);
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `first()` and `second()` are in same controller, you could declare **data** in a class definition.

```
class ...
{
    var $data;

    function first() {
        $this->data['first'] = 1;
        return response()->json($this->data);
    }

    function second() {
        if ($condition) {
            $this->data['second'] = 2;
            return $this->first(); // No redirect
        }
        ...
    }
```

---

If solution above is not feasible anyhow, keep an optional parameter for `first()` in your route definition.

```
Route::get('/first/{data?}', 'SomeController@first')->name('first');
```

Ref - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-parameters

Then, you could redirect to `first()` with data from your `second()` function.

```
function second() {
    if ($condition) {
        return redirect()->route('first', ['data' => ['second' => 2]]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, received parameter can be merged in your `first()` function easily.

```
function first($data = []) {
    $data['first'] = 1;
    return response()->json($data);
}
```